# Email to be sent to subscribers based on the time zone in journey

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, timezone

I have a case in which the emails need to be delivered to the subscribers in my journey based on the time zone, like pst, cst etc.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Either create a new field in the Data Extension or find a way how you would understand which contact belongs to which timezone. If that is a new field, then populate it with a needed value that would symbolize the timezone, for example.
2. By this new field's values or other segmentation rules, you need to separate the audience into several paths by Decision Split (remember to have the DE in the Attribute Group).
3. Then, once you have on the journey canvas needed paths for each timezone, simply add [Wait Until Date Activity](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.mc_jb_wait_until_a_specific_date.htm&type=5) or [Wait by Duration Activity](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.mc_jb_wait_for_a_period_of_time.htm&type=5), where you would select the corresponding timezone.
4. Add Email Activity for each path and those emails are going to be sent at different times depending on the timezone you specified in the Wait Time Activity before.

Comment: Thanks @Niko, will have this tried ....